# How to run mininet in ubuntu in background?

Tags: ubuntu, background-process, mininet

I want to run `mininet` in `ubuntu` in *background* but when I do this:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo mn &
```

I am unable to type any *shell command*, when I press Enter, the `mininet` topology exits.

How to run it completely in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I realized since Mininet needs a terminal, I could use `screen` to create a virtual session and run Mininet there. Then I would just close that terminal and Mininet will keep running in the background inside the shell created by `screen`. I needed this since I was running long tests on a remote machine and I couldn't risk keeping a terminal open on SSH from my machine.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the answer myself. I used the same technique. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First run the mininet:

```
$ sudo mn &
```

then if you type:

```
$ disown
```

Mininet will be detached from your current terminal session.
Finally, If you need to kill it:

```
$ ps aux | grep mn
root     **10258**  0.0  0.0  64716  4020 pts/6    T    01:51   0:00 sudo mn
$ sudo kill -9 **10258**
```

Comment: I didn't know of this, thanks. Do you if it'll detached the process while it's stopped. It seems like the process is stopped. Here is where hypothesis come from: I get `bash: warning: deleting stopped job 1 with process group 23666` when I run the command you posted.

Comment: It is totally normal, It is informing you that bash is not in control of '23666' process, which is (most probably) mininet and any other previously background process.  
If it solved your problem, I would appreciate if you can accept my answer. :)

Comment: I see, true, but it says stopped job. My concern is that if it is stopped or not ?

Comment: you can easily check it, just run `ps aux | grep <process id>` or 'ps aux | grep mn`. :)
If it was stopped, there would not be a process with that process id.

Comment: I was going to but then I thought having a process doesn't mean it is not stopped. humm, Cause to me it seems like the process is alive but it's not executing the `mn` code (stopped). Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah so exactly. After detaching, I get this `ubuntu   24482  0.0  0.0  11740   916 pts/13   S+   08:41   0:00 grep 24473`. Based of the link you commented the process is `S+` meaning Stopped in the foreground. So it's not running. Which makes sense, because I can't connect my controller to mininet network that is detached. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can start the mininet by disabling its CLI, unless you use mininet's python API.

However, after you start the mininet press `ctrl+z` to stall the process. Now you can bring the process back to foreground or put it in background. Note that now the process is stalled (i.e. doing nothing).

So now:

1. If you use `fg` command, it will bring the process to the foreground.
2. If you use `bg` command, it will put the process to background.

Let me know if you need further explanation.